# Keybinds option not working on bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to change keybinds beahvior for boostrap datepicker.

I did this :

```
$('#birthday').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    startView: 0,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    language: "fr",
    autoclose: true,
    keyBinds:
    {
        down: function (widget) {
            if (!widget) {
                // do nothing
            }
            else if (widget.find('.datepicker').is(':visible')) {
                this.date(this.date().clone().add(7, 'd'));
            } else {
                this.date(this.date().clone().subtract(1, 'm'));
            }
            // console.log('Down');
        }
    },
    todayHighlight: true,
}).on('show',function(e) 
{
    console.log('show');
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", SubscripKeyDownHandler);
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", SubscripKeyDownHandler);

}).on('hide',function(e)
{
    console.log('hide');
    document.addEventListener("keydown", SubscripKeyDownHandler);
});
```

And this :

```
$('#birthday').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    startView: 0,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    language: "fr",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
}).on('show',function(e) 
{
    console.log('show');
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", SubscripKeyDownHandler);
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", SubscripKeyDownHandler);
    $(this).data("datepicker").keyBinds({

        down: function (widget) {
            if (!widget) {
                // do nothing
            }
            else if (widget.find('.datepicker').is(':visible')) {
                this.date(this.date().clone().add(7, 'd'));
            } else {
                this.date(this.date().clone().subtract(1, 'm'));
            }
        }
    });
}).on('hide',function(e)
{
    console.log('hide');
    document.addEventListener("keydown", SubscripKeyDownHandler);
});
```

But none of them works.
the second bit of code give me this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyBinds' of undefined
```

While when i'm using it with bootstrap datetimepicker by changing

```
$(this).data("DatePicker").keyBinds({.....
```

By this

```
$(this).data("DateTimePicker").keyBinds({....
```

It works!

Any help please.
Thank's in advance

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Can you post your solution?